# Python: Obtener una lista a partir de otra y un índice

Tags: python, lista

Estoy tratando de hacer una función a la que le pasas una lista y un índice y te da otra lista que contiene el elemento de la primera lista que le has pasado perteneciente al lugar del índice que le has pasado.
He escrito algo así:

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    listresult = []
    listresult = listresult + lista[index]
    return(listresult)
```

Como ya sabréis esto da un error de incompatibilidad de tipos en la línea   `listresult = listresult + lista[index]` Así que trato otra cosa usando el método append():

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    listresult = []
    listresult = listresult.append(lista[index])
    return(listresult)
```

Esto no me da error pero me da `'None'` si hago `>>> print(indextoentry([1,2,3],1))`

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que mi función me devuelva una lista?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué la segunda función me da 'None'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer ejemplo estas sumando una lista y otra cosa (int, float, str, etc) y eso causa un error por incompatibilidad de tipos. Solución:

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    listresult = []
    listresult = listresult + [lista[index]]
    return(listresult)
```

En el segundo estas usando mal el método apend(), tu lo que haces es:

```
listresult = listresult.append(lista[index])
```

Ahora `lisresult` no es una lista sino  el retorno del método apend(), que como no retorna nada es None. Se usa así:

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    listresult = []
    listresult.append(lista[index])
    return(listresult)
```

Simplificando puedes hacer esto:

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    return [lista[index]]
```

O alternativamente:

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    return list(lista[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

> Esto no me da error pero me da 'None'

Esto es porque el método `append` de una [lista](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). **no devuelve un valor**. por eso al hacer la asignación , no se le asigna nada a tu variable `listresult`

```
def indextoentry(lista,index):
    listresult = []
    listresult.append(lista[index])
    return(listresult)


print(indextoentry([1,2,3],1))
```